# Fitting distribution functions in Matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics, probability

I am trying to use the stats toolbox to fit a distribution function. In my case, I already have the PMF (probability mass function, stored in an array) and wanted to fit it. But apparently, the toolbox can only take a vector of samples, from which a histogram is created.

Is there a way to pass it the PMF instead?

Comment: Can you post a short and concise example of what you're doing?

Answer (score 0):

There are [many functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/bq_w_hm.html#bq_w_ie-12) in the Stats toolbox that can fit a bunch of data to a distribution. Say you wanted to fit your data (in an array) to be fit to a normal distribution, you'd use `normfit` like this (example taken from [normfit doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/normfit.html))

```
data = normrnd(10,2,100,2);
[mu,sigma,muci,sigmaci] = normfit(data)
```

If the above doesn't answer you question, can you please include a snippet of code that succinctly describes what you are trying to do?